# Jenkins CI E2E: Doesn't disable firefox download-popup specified by protractor and selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, protractor

Locally my download e2e works fine, my firefox preferences in conf.js correctly disable the browser specific download-popup.

When jenkins runs the test (Jenkins runs on a linux OS, locally I am on macOS), the firefox download-popups aren't disabled.... as the file is never really downloaded.

Also, we are using a custom protracor reporter to make videos of the e2e tests.

See the relevant code below:

conf.js

```js
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--user-data-dir=/tmp']
        w3c: false, // problems with latest chrome driver... browser.actions is causing issues: https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/issues/329
        prefs: {
          download: {
            directory_upgrade: true,
            prompt_for_download: false,
            default_directory: downloadsPath,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      marionette: true,
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['--headless'],
        prefs: {
          'pdfjs.disabled': true,
          'browser.download.folderList': 2,
          'browser.download.dir': downloadsPath,
          'browser.download.panel.shown': false,
          'browser.download.useDownloadDir': true,
          'browser.download.manager.useWindow': false,
          'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force': false,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile': true,
          'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone': false,
          'browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen': false,
          'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false,
          'browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting': false,
          'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete': false,
          'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, '
                                                      + 'application/json, application/vnd.openxmlformats, '
                                                      + 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  onPrepare: async () => {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1400, 1200);
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    const caps = await browser.driver.getCapabilities();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('Browser capabilities: %o', caps);

    const specReporter = new ProtractorReporter();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);
  },
```

download-contract.js

```js
    const downloadBtn = manipulations.getDomObject('download-contract-button', 'id');
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', downloadBtn.getWebElement());

    browser.sleep(5000);

    try {
      await downloads.verifyFileExists(`mandatierung_${mandateId}.docx`);
      const fileSize = await downloads.verifyFileSize(`mandatierung_${mandateId}.docx`);
      expect(fileSize).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(`ERROR: ${err.message}`);
    }
    downloads.removeFile(`mandatierung_${mandateId}.docx`);
```

jenkinsfile... this is how the tests are initiated

```js
sh 'protractor-recorder -b=firefox,chrome -r=1400x1280 -p="--suite full" -f=specs/conf.js -o=/tmp/video-out'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium + Protractactor: Downloading file in chrome & firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457348/selenium-protractactor-downloading-file-in-chrome-firefox)

Comment: added link to answer, also be sure you are adding the proper file extensions in 'saveToDisk' attribute, so it can be downloaded

Comment: lol I posted that. Yeah it works perfectly fine, just when the test is ran by jenkins the firefox popup still shows up. In case I was not targeting the right mime-type, I added many more.